# How to force the camera in IOS to re-focus (in objC code)

Tags: ios

I am playing with the iPhone camera in my app but I could not find a way to take manual control over the timing of re-focusing. In my app, I hope to ensure the best-adjusted image output so a forced re-focus right before taking a shot is needed. More specifically, I would like force the camera to re-focus after the user to hit a button, then take a shot once the re-focusing is complete. What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take a photo automatically at focus in iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423538/how-to-take-a-photo-automatically-at-focus-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: I am sorry that I did not make it clear enough. My target is force a re-focus exactly when I want it, while setting the mode does not guarantee re-focus before every shots taken. That question solved something different(which I was looking for as well, but not in this post). The code guarantee that the shot is taken after and only after re-focus, but it does nothing to call out a re-focus in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Still and Video Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html)

There are three focus modes:

- AVCaptureFocusModeLocked
- AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus
- AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus

And code same how to set focus mode:

```
if ([currentDevice isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus]) {
    CGPoint autofocusPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
    [currentDevice setFocusPointOfInterest:autofocusPoint];
    [currentDevice setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the continous autofocus mode does not guarantee optimal re-focus in some situations, such as when the scene is changing slowly out of focus. It does try to encounter this by re-focus once a few second, but that does not always help. My solution for now is to switch between autoFocus and continousAutoFocus to trigger a re-focus. Though it is not elegant, it does work for my app in which I continuously take full-reso shots of microscope views, which can move out of focus slowly.